# Replace node add/edit form with a custom form

Tags: forms, uri

I have this custom form I made in my module which is responsible for adding/editing a specific node type. I was not able to alter the built-in add/edit form to meet my requirements so I decided to make my own forms using the form API.

The forms are doing good but I need drupal to use my custom forms whenever a user tries to add/edit a node from that specific node type instead of the original drupal's standard forms.

It should be a matter of routing/path. I already tried menu hook but it did not work. So how can I make drupal to replace the content add/edit form for that specific node type with the one I want?

Comment: is it possible to add an alias for node/edit to pint to your form using pathauto?

Comment: @Collins

thanks for the reply. I did try pathauto. unfortunately it didn't work either.

Comment: Pathauto it is! I was doing it the other way around. 

If you could repost your comment as an answer I would happily mark this question answered. 

thank you very much for the tip.

Comment: glad that worked, please see answer below.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about code the OP is not showing in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module. You can use the Url Aliases page to add an alias for all of your custom node edit links.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer or give an example please? I'm not sure how you can create patterns for "edit" links as it seems you can only create patterns for "view" node links.

Comment: @mario It may only work for this use case where he had created a module to change the url for his custom edit forms. You are right, I dont think pathauto will allow you to change the url for the standard node edit forms.

Comment: @MarioAwad I manually defined an alias for the add link but as mentioned by @Collins there was no way to define a patterned alias for the edit links. 

So I ended up saving an alias in code whenever I save a new node.

`node_save($node);
$path = array('source' => "grades/$node->nid",'alias' => "node/$node->nid/edit",); path_save($path);`

Comment: Thanks guys for the clarifications and code. However, the answer's code seems to not use pathauto as the "path_save" function is defined in the core path module and not in pathauto. Please update your answer to reflect that for future users. Cheers.